ES: Why Refresh delete Segment with "committed=false"?
Background：
There exists an index named "i_dm_f_da_enterprise" in ES, and I prohibited auto-refresh by setting "refresh_interval" : -1. I notice that the refresh operation of the index can reduce the occupied disk space after importing data. (POST i_dm_f_da_enterprise/_refresh)
However, I don't understand why it happens. Please someone help to answer the question. Thanks a lot!
For better understanding, I provide the detail of index and segments before and after the refresh below.
Theory Background：

Base on the official document of ES, the process of refresh is combining the documents in buffer into a new segment and save it in filesystem cache. It doesn't effect disk and translog.

Before Refresh：
1. Situation of index and disk space：GET /_cat/indices?v
health status index                           uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   i_dm_f_da_enterprise            vQJl3D2ETvKCCEfbathbXw  36   1  338486628     72052057    804.1gb        384.3gb
2. Amount of segments：GET /_cat/segments/i_dm_f_da_enterprise?v=true
Number：3191
 index                shard prirep ip           segment generation docs.count docs.deleted     size size.memory committed searchable version compound
i_dm_f_da_enterprise 0     p      9.99.112.6  _1uc          2388    3338940      3246825    4.7gb       35454 false     true       8.9.0   false
i_dm_f_da_enterprise 0     p      9.99.112.6  _1uw          2408     194240            0  144.9mb        3716 true      true       8.9.0   true
i_dm_f_da_enterprise 0     p      9.99.112.6  _1vu          2442     167028            0  124.8mb        3652 true      true       8.9.0   true
i_dm_f_da_enterprise 0     p      9.99.112.6  _1xl          2505    2828321        15314      2gb       17086 false     true       8.9.0   false 
Refresh Operation：POST i_dm_f_da_enterprise/_refresh
After Refresh：
1. Situation of index and disk space：GET /_cat/indices?v
 health status index                           uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size green  open   i_dm_f_da_enterprise            vQJl3D2ETvKCCEfbathbXw  36   1  338486628     72052057      584gb        294.9gb
2. Amount of segments：GET /_cat/segments/i_dm_f_da_enterprise?v=true
Number：1973
index                shard prirep ip           segment generation docs.count docs.deleted     size size.memory committed searchable version compound
i_dm_f_da_enterprise 0     p      9.99.112.6  _1uw          2408     194240            0  144.9mb        3716 true      true       8.9.0   true
i_dm_f_da_enterprise 0     p      9.99.112.6  _1vu          2442     167028            0  124.8mb        3652 true      true       8.9.0   true
Observation Conclusion：

Using GET /_cat/indices?v to get the index information after refresh，I notice that the total number of documents(docs.count) and the number of deleted documents(docs.deleted) are unchanged(338486628 and 72052057), but the occupied disk space decreases(384.3gb to 294.9gb)
Using GET /_cat/segments/i_dm_f_da_enterprise?v=true to get the segment information after refresh, I notice that the segments with "committed=false" are deleted，while the number of documents(docs.count) and the number of deleted documents(docs.deleted) in other segements are unchanged, which means those segments are deleted rather than merged.

Question：

Why the changes of doc.count from GET /_cat/indices?v and GET /_cat/segments/i_dm_f_da_enterprise?v=true do not match? The former is unchanged while the latter decreases.
Why refresh delete the segments whose committed=false in GET /_cat/segments? According to the official document, the committed term represents if the segment has been stored in disk. As I know, refresh transfers data into filesystem cache from buffer, and flush transfers segments into disk from filesystem cache. Therefore segments can be stored in disk and get committed=true only after flush is finished, which should be independent of refresh. But it do violate the observation conclusion 2.

Tips：
If my understanding of anything is wrong, please point it out. And I am also haapy if you can provide any document or source code of it.
Official Document：https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-segments.html
